# Right click custom menu is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tablerow, right-click

Right click menu correctly works with its functions.
But the issue is sometimes it is not working properly.
In my view if right clicked on the table row checked the checkbox correctly but after I unchecked and try checked again with right click its not working.

```
$('.check').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
});


$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    }
});


$('tr.check').contextmenu(function (e) {
    $cb = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].selected_check');
    $($cb).attr('checked', 'checked');
    populate_context_menu($cb);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi @menaka , Could you please add jsFiddle link or something so it would be more easy to answer !

Comment: @Rj_01 : Sorry,I didn't use  jsFiddle or other.

Comment: ok I'll try.Thanks men.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my code with some code lines, and its helps to me.

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function () {

   $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

 function isExist(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == id) {
        return true;
    }
 }
  return false;
 }

 $('tr.check').contextmenu(function (e) {

    $cb = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"].selected_check');
        var id = $($cb).attr('id');
        var result = isExist(id);

        if (!result) {
            $('.selected_check').attr('checked', false);
            $('.check').removeClass('highlight_row');
            $('.check').addClass('td_bgcolor');
        }

        $($cb).attr('checked', 'checked');

        populate_context_menu($cb);

           return false;
        });
```